# Listening to incoming texts, in the background

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make my application listen to incoming text messages, in a persistent manner. What would be the best approach for this?

Currently, I've got a working BroadcastReceiver and I'm playing around with implementing a local service for my app. Is somehow implementing the BroadcastReceiver into the service the correct way of doing this? Will the service work in a low memory condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes broadcast receiver is best way for listening to incoming texts.if an incoming sms recvied use IntentService for your work what u want to do on sms recived.u can register a reciver for incoming sms as:

**manifest file**

```
<receiver class="SMSApp">  
   <intent-filter>  
      <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />  
     </intent-filter>  
</receiver>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

**Java File**

```
    public class SMSApp extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSApp"; 
    /* package */
    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"; 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){ 
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){ 
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
          if (bundle != null){
               Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
               SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
               for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                 messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
               }
               for (SmsMessage message : messages){
                    String strFrom = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String strMsg = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
               }
            }    
        } 
    } 
}
```

and **second way** you can register a [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) for `content://sms/inbox` for listening incoming sms in inbox

Answer (score 1):

The broadcast receiver does not need your application to be started, hence is the correct way of listening to incoming texts.

Just make sure to register it in the Manifest